# BIOS lock on my 2015 Dell Inspiron 5558 is set and I can’t get past it

Tags: bios

Can anyone offer me a solution to bypassing the Dell BIOS lock that's keeping me from booting up my wife’s 2015 Dell Inspiron 5558 laptop? I have read a multitude of suggestions many from youtube and many from other sources all of which did not work.

Comment: If it belongs to you / your wife - why not contact Dell directly?

Comment: @Darius according to that logic. 50% of all SU questions should and would be deleted/pointless since we could tell all posters to call the manufacturer. Really silly comment.

Answer (score 0):

> bypassing the Dell BIOS lock

Unfortunately this is super vague on what "lock" means. Do you mean password protection? Or the laptop is stuck in bios because it won't boot to windows?

Here is what you need to do to reset your bios, since i'm going to assume you mean it's password protected.

You're going to want to figure out a way to reset the CMOS.

Open up the back panel or Access Door.

Remove the battery, wait about 1-2 minutes and place it back in, the same way it was before.

What this does is reset your current bios settings to the original settings.

Here is a short video of what I think is someone showing this process.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pis6YSWxmA8